# TrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers performance on OkHttpClient creation

Tags: android, okhttp

I've noticed from profiling that when my `OkHttpClient` is being created by the builder, `TrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers` seems to be taking a long time and is blocking my UI thread on startup. It takes about 111 millis to complete.

Not being extremely familiar with TrustManagers, I was wondering if there might be a faster method that's still secure to provide these to the `OkHttpClient`, and remove this as a concern.

In the mean time, I'll see if I can't defer the creation of my `OkHttpClient` to a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager).build();
```

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/4568075b1a163bec48a8598917e6d6bcc9b2d96b/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.java#L655

But ultimately this is doing what you will need to do, triggering the JVM to load loading SSL related classes, load CA certificates from the system etc.  So it seems unlikely this is a performance win.

Creating the OkHttpClient on a background thread sounds like the best option.